# How to build a group of groups with pattern in an ansible inventory?

Tags: ansible

I want to build up a target host list of hosts which are in both groups DC-North and DC-South and which are not a DB Server.

This was my approach which unfortunately fails:

```
[DC-North]
host1
host2 

[DC-South]
host3
host4 

[dbservers]
host3
host1 

[target:children]
DC-North:&DC-South:!dbservers
```

How would I define this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining it fine.  It's just in the wrong location.  Host patterns go in the playbook

```
- hosts: DC-North:&DC-South:!dbservers
...
```

or on the CLI with `--limit` / `-l`

```
ansible-playbook -l 'DC-North:&DC-South:!dbservers' some_playbook.yml
```

Comment: Is there a way to make a group_vars/DC-North:&DC-South:!dbservers out of this ?

Comment: With a static inventory, I don't think so.  You could use a dynamic inventory to generate the hosts in the question's `target` hostgroup, however....

Answer (score 4):

It is impossible to use patterns, but you can use YAML anchors or reference groups with `children` syntax:

```
apps_web_a:
  hosts: &apps_web_a
    prod-api-1:
    prod-admin-1:

apps_web_b:
  hosts: &apps_web_b
    prod-api-2:
    prod-admin-2:

# YAML anchors:
# apps_web:
#   hosts:
#     <<: *apps_web_a
#     <<: *apps_web_b

apps_web:
  children:
    apps_web_a:
    apps_web_b:
```

Read small note about group of groups: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/intro_inventory.html

> It is also possible to make groups of groups using the :children suffix in INI or the children: entry in YAML. You can apply variables using `:vars` or `vars:`...

That way only algebraic **UNION** set operation is possible...

Follow my question here: https://www.reddit.com/r/ansible/comments/f68yse/is_there_syntax_for_creating_group_from_other/

Answer (score 3):

docs: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inheriting-variable-values-group-variables-for-groups-of-groups

```
[atlanta]
host1
host2

[raleigh]
host2
host3

[southeast:children]
atlanta
raleigh

[southeast:vars]
some_server=foo.southeast.example.com
halon_system_timeout=30
self_destruct_countdown=60
escape_pods=2

[usa:children]
southeast
northeast
southwest
northwest
```

Answer (score -2):

In your inventory change:

```
[target:children]
DC-North
DC-South
```